# Apex динамический Popup Lov

Tags: oracle-apex

Формирую в Apex 5.1 код окато с помощью popup lov.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3 уровень кода(`P11_C183_F5`) зависит от 2-го (`P11_B183_F5`).
Пытаюсь в `list of values` у 3 го уровня написать `select` в зависимости от 2го

```
select upper(tzr),kzr from my_table where kis=:P11_B183_F5
```

И ничего не отбирается

Если написать

```
select upper(tzr),kzr from my_table where kis='212'
```

То вылезут данные по Гаврилов-Яму.

Select для отбора данных пишу вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Здесь добавил тестовое значение, оно выводится
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно в моем случае написать SQl Query в List of Values ?

Comment: Может, проблема в `Cascading LOV Parent Item(s)`? У итема `P11_C183_F5` в свойствах впишите в это поле `P11_B183_F5`. Это если я правильно понял проблему.

Comment: Да в этом косяк и был